# $\int fd\mu=\sup\{\int_{E}fd\mu:E\in S,\mu(E)<+\infty\}$

Tags: measure-theory

I'm trying to prove the next proposition:

Let $(X,S)$ be a measurable space. Let $f$ be a $S-$measurable function non negative such that $\int fd\mu<+\infty.$ Then
$$\int fd\mu=\sup\{\int_{E}fd\mu:E\in S,\mu(E)<+\infty\}.$$

Because of $E\subset X$ we have $\int_{E} fd\mu\leq\int fd\mu$ and therefore $$\int fd\mu\geq\sup\{\int_{E}fd\mu:E\in S,\mu(E)<+\infty\}.$$

For the other inequality I have trouble. Even I don't know why is necessary the condition of $\int fd\mu<+\infty.$

Any kind of help is thanked in advance.

Comment: If $\int fd\mu = \infty$, then the set on the right side will be unbounded.

Comment: For the other direction, recall that the definition of the $\sigma$-algebra $S$ on $X$ requires $X\in S$. Since $\mu(X)\lt\infty$, thus $\int f~\mathrm d\mu$ is an element of the set in question and the other direction follows by the definition of $\sup$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\operatorname{d}}$
Since $\int_X f \d\mu<+\infty$, $\mu\{x\in X|f(x)=+\infty\}=0$. For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, let
$ X_n=\{x\in X|f(x)>n\}\in S,$
then $X_n\subset X_{n+1}$ and $\mu(X-\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} X_n)=0 $. 
Hence $f_n=f\chi_{X_n}$ is an increasing sequence of non negative measurable functions which converges to $f$ a.e..
By Levi's theorem, $\int_{X_n} f\d\mu=\int_X f_n\d\mu\to \int_X f\d\mu $. Hence the other direction is true.

Comment: Good answer! Thanks @C.Ding.